# How can I rename the rows (not columns) of a Kable in R, specifically in RMarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rename, kable

I run a code that pulls from different places in order to create the test_results variable. This variable I have put into a kable so I can control the output of it better in the HTML file I am creating. The code below creates a kable table exactly how I want it formatted, and I was able to rename the column names how I want those. What can I add to this code to rename the row names? I have tried row.names and other things but I either get an error or that tibble is depreciated with the function I was trying to use.

```
kable(head(test_results), caption = "**Test Results**",
      col.names = c("Test Result",
                    "N",
                    "Total"))%>%
  
  kable_material(c("striped", "hover"))
```

Comment: When you tried to rename rows and received a deprecation notice, what code did you try?

Comment: I tried this, which just gives me an error. rownames(in_transit, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "row"

Comment: adding row.names to the end of it doesn't have any error, but it doesn't change the output

Comment: Change row names *before* sending to `kable`, since that function changes it from a frame (that understands what row names are) to a string or other struct (which does not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change row names before sending it to `kable`.

```r
library(kable)
library(kableExtra) # kable_material
mt <- mtcars[1:3, 1:4]
kable(mt) %>% kable_material(c("striped", "hover"))
```

[image: kable/html with original row names]

```r
rownames(mt) <- c("hello", "world", "again")
kable(mt) %>% kable_material(c("striped", "hover"))
```

[image: kable/html with row names adjusted]

Comment: I don't think I can, because I am pulling in my data into the variable from databases. So it isn't ever in a dataframe I don't think.

Comment: ```{r}
rownames(in_transit) <- c("hello", "world", "again", "well", "nice", "wellpp")
kable(head(in_transit), caption = "**Incoming Samples**",
      col.names = c("Submitter Name",
                    "N",
                    "Total")) %>%
  
  kable_material(c("striped", "hover"))
```

Comment: I tried that ^^ and this is the error  I got  Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length

Comment: That means that the length of the vector on the right side of the `<-` is not the same as the number of rows in the frame. If your frame has `n` rows, then the vector must be length `n`. The exception to this is if you set a subset of the names, as in `rownames(mt)[2:3] <- c('a','b')`.